# Scipy Minimize uses a NoneType

Tags: python, scipy, python-idle, linear-regression

I'm trying to code a multiple linear regression.  Here's the line of code where my program raises an error:

```
least = optimize.minimize(residsq(xmat, ylist, coeff), coeff, constraints = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': sum(resid(xmat, ylist, coeff))}), method = 'BFGS') # Choose the coefficients that minimize the sum of the residuals squared subject to keeping the sum of the residuals equal to 0.
```

xmat is a list of vectors: [[3,5,2],[3,1,6],[7,2,3], [9,-2,0]].  ylist is a list of the same length as xmat: [5,2,7,7].  coeff is the coefficient list, initially [mean(ylist), 0, 0, 0] ([constant, b_0, b_1, b_2]).  resid is the list of residuals for each point, and residsq is the N2 norm of the residuals (sqrt of sum of squares).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    import linregtest
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\linregtest.py", line 4, in <module>
    out = linreg.multilinreg(xmat, ylist, True)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\linreg.py", line 120, in multilinreg
    least = optimize.minimize(residsq(xmat, ylist, coeff), coeff, constraints = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': sum(resid(xmat, ylist, coeff))}), method = 'BFGS') # Choose the coefficients that minimize the sum of the residuals squared subject to keeping the sum of the residuals equal to 0.
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py", line 302, in minimize
    RuntimeWarning)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\idlelib\PyShell.py", line 60, in idle_showwarning
    file.write(warnings.formatwarning(message, category, filename,
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Where does file come from, and how do I suppress this error?

EDIT: Solve one problem, find another.  Maybe you can help me determine where SciPy is calling a float?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import linregtest
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\linregtest.py", line 4, in <module>
    out = linreg.multilinreg(xmat, ylist, True)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\linreg.py", line 123, in multilinreg
    least = optimize.minimize(residsq(xmat, ylist, coeff), coeff, constraints = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': sumresid(xmat, ylist, coeff)}), method = 'SLSQP') # Choose the coefficients that minimize the sum of the residuals squared subject to keeping the sum of the residuals equal to 0.
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py", line 364, in minimize
    constraints, **options)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\slsqp.py", line 301, in _minimize_slsqp
    meq = sum(map(len, [atleast_1d(c['fun'](x, *c['args'])) for c in cons['eq']]))
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\slsqp.py", line 301, in <listcomp>
    meq = sum(map(len, [atleast_1d(c['fun'](x, *c['args'])) for c in cons['eq']]))
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Comment: This looks like a problem with PyShell/the gui shell you're using, not Numpy. It appears that Numpy is showing a warning, and for some reason PyShell is trying to write that to a nonexistent file object.

Comment: It looks like a bug in IDLE on python 3. I have the same problem with any warnings that are supposed to be printed to the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just edited my python 3.2 IDLE, PyShell.py (fixing lines 59 and 62)

```
def idle_showwarning(message, category, filename, lineno,
                     file=None, line=None):
    if file is None:
        file = sys.stderr #warning_stream
    try:
        file.write(warnings.formatwarning(message, category, filename,
                                          lineno, line=line))
```

use `sys.stderr` instead of the global `warning_stream` which uses `sys.__stderr__`. `sys.__stderr__` is None in my case. I don't know why a global is used.

the call to `warnings.formatwarning` had an extra invalid `file` keyword.

Now, I get the warning printed, for example

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.uint(1) - np.uint(2)

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Programs\Python32\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw", line 1
    try:
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in ulong_scalars
>>> 4294967295
>>>
```

*edit:*

searching for python bug reports

http://bugs.python.org/issue12438 wrong `file` argument has been fixed

http://bugs.python.org/issue13582 problems with `sys.__stderr__ is None` is open

Comment: Thanks, but now I have a new problem.  Updated my question because traceback is too long.

Comment: What the traceback says: your giving numerical values instead of a callable. In your constraint you define 'fun' as an array not as a function. I guess you need to define a function or use a `lambda` function. The documentation should explain it, I never worked with the new `minimize` function.

Comment: Did you solve the overflow error? It's likely the result you've got there isn't the right answer.

Comment: The overflow error in my example was just to illustrate that it shows up correctly. (-1 cannot be represented as unsigned integer, so it overflows. That's numpy behavior by design.)